# Aligning background images

Tags: html, css, layout, background-image

I'm trying to responsively (full width!) align three background images + text.
here is the layout:

```
********************************************************
*                           *                          *
*                           * background 2 (width 50%) *
*                           *                          *
* background 1 (width 50%)  ****************************
*                           *                          *
*                           * background 3 (width 50%) *
*                           *                          *
********************************************************
```

whatever I do, I can't manage to accomplish this. I searched everywhere and couldn't find a solution. Can someone help please? the requirements are that this block will always stay the same height, no fixed width cause it has to be responsive (images shrink accordingly when browser resizes) and on mobile it should become three rows. On each background I need to add different amount of text but the whole block has to always stay the same height!
Also I don't want to use javascript, Is it possible to accomplish this with only html/css and maintain browser compatibility?

Please help!

Thanks!!!

Comment: What's the reason of not wanting to use javascript?

Comment: Cause I prefer to use HTML/CSS only if possible. Is it?

Answer (score 0):

```
.img-container {
    width:50%;float:left;
}    

.img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

---

```
<div class="img-container">
     <div>Text here with styling</div>
     <img class="img" src="img-link"></img>
</div>
<div class="img-container">
     <div>Text here with styling</div>
     <img class="img" src="img-link"></img>
     <div>Text here with styling</div>
     <div class="img" src="img-link"></div>
</div>
```

Adjust the text above images as u need...

Comment: Thanks! it works partially (your second example) cause you need to add min-height to each background, the only problem is I need to use media queries to change the max-height as the browser shrinks. Is the any other way to accomplish this without forcing min-height but still keep the aspect ratio of the images? For example: if the large image is 1000x900 and the smaller images are 1000x450 I want it to shrink to the viewport current dimensions. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works for you.

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}
#left {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
}
#right {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
}
#right div {
  height: 50%;
}
#right div:first-child {
  background: blue;
}
#right div:last-child {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="left">background 1</div>
  <div id="right">
    <div>background 2</div>
    <div>background 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this solution is not responsive

Comment: Click the Full page button and see if it's responsive enough.

Comment: It's not, images height are always 200px, I need it to change when width changes

Comment: See example here: https://www.perfectomobile.com/ when browser shrinks, images shrink accordingly. I think they are doing this with JS

Comment: You said: "the requirements are that this block will always stay the same height"

Comment: I'm sorry, I guess I failed to explain myself. Is it now clear what I'm after? Is there a solution?